# Getting error exporting org doc because it has #+TITLE

Tags: org-mode, pandoc

Getting this error after installed the latest org and ox-pandoc packages.

```
apply: Wrong type argument: listp, #("Some title" 0 48 (:parent (#0)))
```

Any pointers?

Update: 
This is org-version:

```
Org mode version 9.0.9 (9.0.9-elpa @ /home/sbay/emacs.d/elpa/org-20170622/)
```

This is the debug info:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp #("Myinit.org" 0 10 (:parent (#1))))
  org-element-set-contents(#("Myinit.org" 0 10 (:parent (#0))))
  apply(org-element-set-contents #("Myinit.org" 0 10 (:parent (#0))) nil)
  #[257 "\211\305\306\307#\310\311\211:\204
  org-element-map((#("Myinit.org" 0 10 (:parent #0))) plain-text #[257 "\211\305\306\307#\310\311\211:\204
  org-export--get-inbuffer-options([cl-struct-org-export-backend html nil ((bold . org-html-bold) (center-block . org-html-center-block) (clock . org-html-clock) (code . org-html-code) (drawer . org-html-drawer) (dynamic-block . org-html-dynamic-block) (entity . org-html-entity) (example-block . org-html-example-block) (export-block . org-html-export-block) (export-snippet . org-html-export-snippet) (fixed-width . org-html-fixed-width) (footnote-definition . org-html-footnote-definition) (footnote-reference . org-html-footnote-reference) (headline . org-html-headline) (horizontal-rule . org-html-horizontal-rule) (inline-src-block . org-html-inline-src-block) (inlinetask . org-html-inlinetask) (inner-template . org-html-inner-template) (italic . org-html-italic) (item . org-html-item) (keyword . org-html-keyword) (latex-environment . org-html-latex-environment) (latex-fragment . org-html-latex-fragment) (line-break . org-html-line-break) (link . org-html-link) (node-property . org-html-node-property) (paragraph . org-html-paragraph) (plain-list . org-html-plain-list) (plain-text . org-html-plain-text) (planning . org-html-planning) (property-drawer . org-html-property-drawer) (quote-block . org-html-quote-block) (radio-target . org-html-radio-target) (section . org-html-section) (special-block . org-html-special-block) (src-block . org-html-src-block) (statistics-cookie . org-html-statistics-cookie) (strike-through . org-html-strike-through) (subscript . org-html-subscript) (superscript . org-html-superscript) (table . org-html-table) (table-cell . org-html-table-cell) (table-row . org-html-table-row) (target . org-html-target) (template . org-html-template) (timestamp . org-html-timestamp) (underline . org-html-underline) (verbatim . org-html-verbatim) (verse-block . org-html-verse-block)) ((:html-doctype "HTML_DOCTYPE" nil org-html-doctype) (:html-container "HTML_CONTAINER" nil org-html-container-element) (:description "DESCRIPTION" nil nil newline) (:keywords "KEYWORDS" nil nil space) (:html-html5-fancy nil "html5-fancy" org-html-html5-fancy) (:html-link-use-abs-url nil "html-link-use-abs-url" org-html-link-use-abs-url) (:html-link-home "HTML_LINK_HOME" nil org-html-link-home) (:html-link-up "HTML_LINK_UP" nil org-html-link-up) (:html-mathjax "HTML_MATHJAX" nil "" space) (:html-postamble nil "html-postamble" org-html-postamble) (:html-preamble nil "html-preamble" org-html-preamble) (:html-head "HTML_HEAD" nil org-html-head newline) (:html-head-extra "HTML_HEAD_EXTRA" nil org-html-head-extra newline) (:subtitle "SUBTITLE" nil nil parse) (:html-head-include-default-style nil "html-style" org-html-head-include-default-style) (:html-head-include-scripts nil "html-scripts" org-html-head-include-scripts) (:html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors nil nil org-html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors) (:html-divs nil nil org-html-divs) (:html-checkbox-type nil nil org-html-checkbox-type) (:html-extension nil nil org-html-extension) (:html-footnote-format nil nil org-html-footnote-format) (:html-footnote-separator nil nil org-html-footnote-separator) (:html-footnotes-section nil nil org-html-footnotes-section) (:html-format-drawer-function nil nil org-html-format-drawer-function) (:html-format-headline-function nil nil org-html-format-headline-function) (:html-format-inlinetask-function nil nil org-html-format-inlinetask-function) (:html-home/up-format nil nil org-html-home/up-format) (:html-indent nil nil org-html-indent) (:html-infojs-options nil nil org-html-infojs-options) (:html-infojs-template nil nil org-html-infojs-template) (:html-inline-image-rules nil nil org-html-inline-image-rules) (:html-link-org-files-as-html nil nil org-html-link-org-files-as-html) (:html-mathjax-options nil nil org-html-mathjax-options) (:html-mathjax-template nil nil org-html-mathjax-template) (:html-metadata-timestamp-format nil nil org-html-metadata-timestamp-format) (:html-postamble-format nil nil org-html-postamble-format) (:html-preamble-format nil nil org-html-preamble-format) (:html-table-align-individual-fields nil nil org-html-table-align-individual-fields) (:html-table-caption-above nil nil org-html-table-caption-above) (:html-table-data-tags nil nil org-html-table-data-tags) (:html-table-header-tags nil nil org-html-table-header-tags) (:html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column nil nil org-html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column) (:html-tag-class-prefix nil nil org-html-tag-class-prefix) (:html-text-markup-alist nil nil org-html-text-markup-alist) (:html-todo-kwd-class-prefix nil nil org-html-todo-kwd-class-prefix) (:html-toplevel-hlevel nil nil org-html-toplevel-hlevel) (:html-use-infojs nil nil org-html-use-infojs) (:html-validation-link nil nil org-html-validation-link) (:html-viewport nil nil org-html-viewport) (:html-inline-images nil nil org-html-inline-images) ...) ((:filter-options . org-html-infojs-install-script) (:filter-final-output . org-html-final-function)) nil (104 "Export to HTML" ((72 "As HTML buffer" org-html-export-as-html) (104 "As HTML file" org-html-export-to-html) (111 "As HTML file and open" (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-html-export-to-html t s v b) (org-open-file (org-html-export-to-html nil s v b)))))))])
  org-export-get-environment([cl-struct-org-export-backend html nil ((bold . org-html-bold) (center-block . org-html-center-block) (clock . org-html-clock) (code . org-html-code) (drawer . org-html-drawer) (dynamic-block . org-html-dynamic-block) (entity . org-html-entity) (example-block . org-html-example-block) (export-block . org-html-export-block) (export-snippet . org-html-export-snippet) (fixed-width . org-html-fixed-width) (footnote-definition . org-html-footnote-definition) (footnote-reference . org-html-footnote-reference) (headline . org-html-headline) (horizontal-rule . org-html-horizontal-rule) (inline-src-block . org-html-inline-src-block) (inlinetask . org-html-inlinetask) (inner-template . org-html-inner-template) (italic . org-html-italic) (item . org-html-item) (keyword . org-html-keyword) (latex-environment . org-html-latex-environment) (latex-fragment . org-html-latex-fragment) (line-break . org-html-line-break) (link . org-html-link) (node-property . org-html-node-property) (paragraph . org-html-paragraph) (plain-list . org-html-plain-list) (plain-text . org-html-plain-text) (planning . org-html-planning) (property-drawer . org-html-property-drawer) (quote-block . org-html-quote-block) (radio-target . org-html-radio-target) (section . org-html-section) (special-block . org-html-special-block) (src-block . org-html-src-block) (statistics-cookie . org-html-statistics-cookie) (strike-through . org-html-strike-through) (subscript . org-html-subscript) (superscript . org-html-superscript) (table . org-html-table) (table-cell . org-html-table-cell) (table-row . org-html-table-row) (target . org-html-target) (template . org-html-template) (timestamp . org-html-timestamp) (underline . org-html-underline) (verbatim . org-html-verbatim) (verse-block . org-html-verse-block)) ((:html-doctype "HTML_DOCTYPE" nil org-html-doctype) (:html-container "HTML_CONTAINER" nil org-html-container-element) (:description "DESCRIPTION" nil nil newline) (:keywords "KEYWORDS" nil nil space) (:html-html5-fancy nil "html5-fancy" org-html-html5-fancy) (:html-link-use-abs-url nil "html-link-use-abs-url" org-html-link-use-abs-url) (:html-link-home "HTML_LINK_HOME" nil org-html-link-home) (:html-link-up "HTML_LINK_UP" nil org-html-link-up) (:html-mathjax "HTML_MATHJAX" nil "" space) (:html-postamble nil "html-postamble" org-html-postamble) (:html-preamble nil "html-preamble" org-html-preamble) (:html-head "HTML_HEAD" nil org-html-head newline) (:html-head-extra "HTML_HEAD_EXTRA" nil org-html-head-extra newline) (:subtitle "SUBTITLE" nil nil parse) (:html-head-include-default-style nil "html-style" org-html-head-include-default-style) (:html-head-include-scripts nil "html-scripts" org-html-head-include-scripts) (:html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors nil nil org-html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors) (:html-divs nil nil org-html-divs) (:html-checkbox-type nil nil org-html-checkbox-type) (:html-extension nil nil org-html-extension) (:html-footnote-format nil nil org-html-footnote-format) (:html-footnote-separator nil nil org-html-footnote-separator) (:html-footnotes-section nil nil org-html-footnotes-section) (:html-format-drawer-function nil nil org-html-format-drawer-function) (:html-format-headline-function nil nil org-html-format-headline-function) (:html-format-inlinetask-function nil nil org-html-format-inlinetask-function) (:html-home/up-format nil nil org-html-home/up-format) (:html-indent nil nil org-html-indent) (:html-infojs-options nil nil org-html-infojs-options) (:html-infojs-template nil nil org-html-infojs-template) (:html-inline-image-rules nil nil org-html-inline-image-rules) (:html-link-org-files-as-html nil nil org-html-link-org-files-as-html) (:html-mathjax-options nil nil org-html-mathjax-options) (:html-mathjax-template nil nil org-html-mathjax-template) (:html-metadata-timestamp-format nil nil org-html-metadata-timestamp-format) (:html-postamble-format nil nil org-html-postamble-format) (:html-preamble-format nil nil org-html-preamble-format) (:html-table-align-individual-fields nil nil org-html-table-align-individual-fields) (:html-table-caption-above nil nil org-html-table-caption-above) (:html-table-data-tags nil nil org-html-table-data-tags) (:html-table-header-tags nil nil org-html-table-header-tags) (:html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column nil nil org-html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column) (:html-tag-class-prefix nil nil org-html-tag-class-prefix) (:html-text-markup-alist nil nil org-html-text-markup-alist) (:html-todo-kwd-class-prefix nil nil org-html-todo-kwd-class-prefix) (:html-toplevel-hlevel nil nil org-html-toplevel-hlevel) (:html-use-infojs nil nil org-html-use-infojs) (:html-validation-link nil nil org-html-validation-link) (:html-viewport nil nil org-html-viewport) (:html-inline-images nil nil org-html-inline-images) ...) ((:filter-options . org-html-infojs-install-script) (:filter-final-output . org-html-final-function)) nil (104 "Export to HTML" ((72 "As HTML buffer" org-html-export-as-html) (104 "As HTML file" org-html-export-to-html) (111 "As HTML file and open" (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-html-export-to-html t s v b) (org-open-file (org-html-export-to-html nil s v b)))))))] nil (:output-file "./myinit.html"))
  org-export-as(html nil nil nil (:output-file "./myinit.html"))
  org-export-to-file(html "./myinit.html" nil nil nil nil nil)
  (let* ((extension (concat "." (or (plist-get ext-plist :html-extension) org-html-extension "html"))) (file (org-export-output-file-name extension subtreep)) (org-export-coding-system org-html-coding-system)) (org-export-to-file (quote html) file async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist))
  org-html-export-to-html(nil nil nil nil)
  (org-open-file (org-html-export-to-html nil s v b))
  (if a (org-html-export-to-html t s v b) (org-open-file (org-html-export-to-html nil s v b)))
  (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-html-export-to-html t s v b) (org-open-file (org-html-export-to-html nil s v b))))(nil nil nil nil)
  org-export-dispatch(nil)
  call-interactively(org-export-dispatch nil nil)
  command-execute(org-export-dispatch)
```

Comment: Try enabling debugging by `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to see what function is being called when this happens. From the looks of the error, the function expects a list of Org elements but gets just a single one of them, which looks like a bug in Org code. So, posting the output of `M-x org-version` would also help to find out whether this is a possibly already fixed bug.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I updated the post with the info requested.

Comment: Can you see if this will help: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-08/msg00315.html

Comment: C-u M-x org-reload by itself was not enough, Kaushal's link had the full sequence. Thanks.